# pgadmin4 inside a Docker container doesn't login

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin-4

when i tried to login in pgadmin4 with this credentials

i get this error

Unable to connect to server:

connection to server at "db" (172.18.0.3), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your question title is bad: it suggest you cannot login to pgadmin instead of a database server from pgadmin.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the hostname in your server registration page to `localhost`. This is because container name is only accessible from other containers within the same docker user defined network.